# Google plus custom share button callback

Tags: javascript, google-plus, share

Is there a way to add callback when user shares something to custom share buttons?

Currently I open a share dialog in a popup:

```
<a data-height="600" data-title="Google+" class="popup" href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=MY_URL">Share</a>

$('.popup').click(function(event) {
        var width  = 575,
            height = $(this).data('height'),
            left   = ($(window).width()  - width)  / 2,
            top    = ($(window).height() - height) / 2,
            url    = this.href,
            opts   = 'status=1' +
                ',width='  + width  +
                ',height=' + height +
                ',top='    + top    +
                ',left='   + left;

        window.open(url, $(this).data('title'), opts);

        event.preventDefault();
    });
```

In documentation: https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/ they say, that we can specify callback with data-onendinteraction when using their js api. Can't find a way to do it with custom share link.

Comment: Did you manage to figure out how to do this?

Comment: No, unfortunately not.

Answer (score -1):

It seem like there is no way to do so.
There is an open issue with this exact feature request.

https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=232

Consider starring and supporting it, but it's already opened for three years. It doesn't seem like Google tries hard to implement it.

Comment: If it is not a direct answer to an old post, and if its an question, you may create a new question.